# How to delete rows in a pandas df that have the same values, but in different sequence?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I wrote the following code in Python:

```
df=df.groupby(['card1', 'card2']).size().reset_index().rename(columns{0:'count'})
df['hand']=df['card1']+', '+df['card2']
df
```

which gives the following output:

```
card1   card2   count   hand
  2c     7h       1     2c, 7h
  2c     7s       1     2c, 7s
  7h     2c       1     7h, 2c
```

I would like to get the ouput like this:

```
card1   card2   count   hand
  2c     7h       2     2c, 7h
  2c     7s       1     2c, 7s
```

For me it doesn't really matter which card is the first (so output 1 and 3 should be counted as the same hand. I can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a step back, sort each row via [`np.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html), then use `groupby` + `size`:

```
cols = ['card1', 'card2']

res = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[cols].values, axis=1), columns=cols)\
        .groupby(cols).size().rename('count').reset_index()
```

If you need a comma-separated series, it's more efficient to create this on your smaller result:

```
res['hand'] = res['card1'] + ', ' + res['card2']

print(res)

  card1 card2  count    hand
0    2c    7h      2  2c, 7h
1    2c    7s      1  2c, 7s
```

Comment: This results in the following error: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'.

Comment: @Jan, See update, looks like you need to filter by columns since your input dataframe consists of more than just strings.